# How to add app delegate back to mainwindow.xib

Tags: ios, delegates, xib, nib

**short answer:**

drag a Object from Object library and set its class to delegate.

Details see the answer below.

I accidentally removed app delegate from mainwindow.xib. I looked into everywhere but still cannot find a way to add it back. I tried to find it online and still got no result. Can anyone help me to fix it? Thank you.

**My project**

[image: My project]

**Other's project**

[image: Other's project, which has appdelegate]

**Main.m**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically your AppDelegate won't be referenced in any .xib files. Rather, your main.m will instantiate an instance of AppDelegate (via the `UIApplicationMain` function), and then your AppDelegate will instantiate one or more of your view controllers, which in turn will unarchive some views based on .xib files.

The entry point for your app in `main.m`, where your AppDelegate gets instantiated and starts up your app, should look like this (If your app delegate has a different class name, use that instead of `AppDelegate`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

…But if your application has a MainWindow.xib, the above is all incorrect, and you do want to make an instance of your AppDelegate in MainWindow.xib. To do that, just drag a generic Object from the Object Library into the Objects area in IB, and then go to the Identity Inspector and set the Class field to the class name of your App Delegate. (You can get to the Object Library and Identity Inspector from View/Utilities.

Comment: Thanks @yuji, so what should I do to make it back?

Comment: I'm confused—what is it specifically you're not able to do because of the "absence" of your app delegate? I say "absence" because it normally isn't referenced by mainwindow.xib in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I uploaded a image. My question is how to add the appdelegate to nib.

Comment: You shouldn't do that: if you do, you'd be creating a new instance of your `AppDelegate` class instead of connecting to the actual AppDelegate instance for your application. If you really want to have a reference to your `AppDelegate` in a view controller, this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710062/using-interface-builder-efficiently will tell you both 1) how to do it programatically and 2) why doing so wouldn't be very good MVC.

Comment: Thanks @yuji, actually I changed it to nil because I try to follow others project. Now I change it back and still cannot see PushBizAppDelegate in the mainwindow.xib. Since I don't have appdelegate, I cannot set its class to MyAppDelegate, and cannot link it to file owner.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7510/discussion-between-yuji-and-thinkchris)

Comment: I upload a image of others project which works. If I remove "Custom Tab Bar App Delegate" in mainwindow.xib, I cannot add it back. Why.

Comment: yuji, can you elaborate on why "But if your application has a MainWindow.xib, the above is all incorrect, and you do want to make an instance of your AppDelegate in MainWindow.xib"?

I'd like to understand that...