# appdelegate object in xib

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, xib

I am trying to follow the apple photopicker example which has an appdelegate object  in an .xib file. How does an appdelegate object get into a xib file, and why is it important?

In my app I want a navigation controller like the photopicker example has. My test work has not included a navigation controller and I am having difficulty inserting one into my test work now that it has just a view controller because the interface builder seems to have made up its mind to not allow the addition. Will it be easiest for me to just start over with a new app that has the navigation controller architecture and then add in copies of my test work methods and classes. Or is starting over unnecessary? I suspect that inserting the appdelegate object into the xib would allow me to use the exist test work more directly.

**update 0**

I think I followed the instructions in your answer. Xcode suggested `_viewController` and I changed that. My app is for both iPad and iPhone (and I am working only on iPad now), so it is a little more complicated, I think. I compile fine, but I still see no appdelegate object in my xib file even though PhotoPicker's xib file has one.

I suspect I need to hook up some objects still, but I could use some help with that, too. In PhotoPicker the Connections Inspector for the Navigation Controller says that the Referencing Outlet is between `navController` and `AppDelegate`, and the Connections Inspector for the AppDelegate says that the Referencing Outlet is between `delegate` and `File's Owner`. But because my xib file has no (BS)AppDelegate object, I don't know how to hook up without it.

```
@interface BSAppDelegate ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@end


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[BSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BSViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[BSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BSViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**update 0**

Answer (score 3):

Inside (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions, you can add uinavigationcontroller like this:

```
UIViewController *viewController = … //load your first view controller with the initial xib here
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

Comment: Your answer looks promising. Please look at my edited question because I am not quite there yet.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand your requirements. I think you want to add uinavigationcontroller on the top of your viewcontroller. If you want to have AppDelegate object in your xib, you can see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206502/how-to-add-app-delegate-back-to-mainwindow-xib

Comment: Please add your comment to the question so I can accept it. Btw, I stumbled using your link response because when I first looked for an `Object` in the Object Library, I did not realize there was literally one named `Object` and tried to trick some other object into being one. My bad, but that sort of thing takes a lot of my learning time. Thanks.

Comment: @zerowords: my comment is linked to another answer, so if you found the answer is good for you, just vote it up :)